# What is the use of LoopAction which is use as object in FormAction class in rasa 3.x?

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa-x, rasa-sdk

I have been figuring out the proper explanation of *LoopAction* object in Rasa 3.x. I have read the [official document of rasa 3.x](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/reference/rasa/core/actions/forms/). But I am not getting satisfied information from it.
Do anyone can help me with it? If anyone can provide proper information with example like how you can implement *LoopAction* in Rasa 3.x then it will be helpful for me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added the link of  documentation where you can see details about LoopAction. But I could not implement it. I will highlight my exact doubt